# Rails translate enum in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, enums, translate

I am currently working on statistics, so I get an array containing all my data. The problem is that this data contains enums and that I would like to translate them without overwriting the rest.

Here is a given example that contains my array (it contains several hundred) :

```
#<Infosheet id: 90, date: "2018-04-22 00:00:00", number: 7, way: "home", gender: "man", age: "age1", district: "", intercommunal: "", appointment: true, othertype: "", otherorientation: "", user_id: 3, created_at: "2018-04-22 17:51:16", updated_at: "2018-04-22 17:51:16", typerequest_id: 168, orientation_id: 188, info_number: nil, city_id: 105>
```

I would like to translate the enums of "way" or "gender" or "age", while retaining the rest of the data, because currently, if I make a translation in the console, it crushes everything else.

Do you know how to make that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over all the enum attributes and get their values. Later you can merge and pass a new hash containing converted values

```
ENUM_COLUMNS = %i[way gender age] # Equivalent to [:way, :gender, :age]

def convert_enums
  overrided_attributes = {}
  ENUM_COLUMNS.each { |column| overrided_attributes[column.to_s] = self[column] }
  attributes.merge(overrided_attributes)
end
```

NOTE:

While `infosheet.gender` returns you `male` or `female`
`infosheet[:gender]` will return you the respective integer value `0` or `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can test this if you use [translate enum](https://rubygems.org/gems/translate_enum) gem :

```
a = Infosheet.group(:gender).count
{“male”=>30, “female”=>6532}
```

Create a hash

```
r = Hash.new
```

And populate this with :

```
a.each {|s| puts r[Infosheet.translated_gender(s[0])]=s[1] } 
r
```

result  :

```
 {“homme”=>30, “femme”=>6532}
```